# async/await -- is this what it's doing?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

Are these two bits of code essentially doing the same thing and can be used in the same way?

```
// dbGrab returns a promise.

// OPTION A
var consoleFoo = function(refToFoo){
  dbGrab(refToFoo)
    .then(function(foo){
      console.log(foo);
    })
}

// OPTION B
var consoleFooES7 = async function(refToFoo){
  var foo = await dbGrab(refToFoo);
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are identical.

Comment: @zerkms No, they're not, because the async function returns a promise.

Comment: @torazaburo the return result is not used, so it does not matter.

Comment: Huh? How do you know how this is called?

Comment: @torazaburo just ask the OP for that.

Comment: @user3881307 --- how do you invoke the `consoleFoo` function?

Comment: @zerkms We don't need to ask him. He can invoke it however he wants. However he invokes it, in order to be "identical" as you claim, the result should be the same, which in this case it's not.

Comment: @torazaburo it does not matter in terms of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between this two functions is that first returns `undefined` and second returns `Promise`. I've modified them slightly so that they almost equal.

```
var consoleFoo = function(refToFoo){
  return dbGrab(refToFoo)
    .then(function(foo){
      console.log(foo);
    })
}

// OPTION B
var consoleFooES7 = async function(refToFoo){
  var foo = await dbGrab(refToFoo);
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Also you can take into consideration that for now (early 2016) native promises works slower then `bluebird` for example, so that first approach could be faster. Depending on target of compillation: ES5 or ES6 the compiler from ES7 could produce the mess or the code that use native `Promises` or `Generators`. In most cases its not an issue but I can't recomend ES7 slyle for highload tasks like routing for now.